# Nancy.Owin vs Nancy.Hosting.Self with topshelf

Tags: owin, nancy, topshelf

1) What is the differences between setting up with the two different packages? Is one more supported than the other?

I had a project using Nancy.Hosting.Self and didn't find any article about how to setup windows authentication, while I did find it for Nancy.Owin as middleware. I have now switched to Nancy.owin.

Here are a few different questions.

2) The jsonformatter can be configured in both the nancy bootstrapper as in the owin endpoint topshelf.
Where should I configure the formatter? If configured in the topshelf owin endpoint, will this be applied in the nancy bootstrapper as well?

3) With the nancy endpoint in topshelf there was an option to set firewall rules and url reservations. I can't find this in the owin endpoint.

```
private static void CreateHost(HostConfigurator host)
    {
        var logger = SetupLogging();
        host.UseSerilog(logger);
        host.UseLinuxIfAvailable();
        //sc => serviceconfigurator, ls => licenseService
        host.Service<WebService>(sc =>
        {
            sc.ConstructUsing(name => new WebService(_config));
            sc.WhenStarted(ls => ls.Start());
            sc.WhenStopped(ls => ls.Stop());
            sc.OwinEndpoint(app =>
            {
                app.ConfigureHttp(configuration =>
                {
                    //use json.net serializer
                    configuration.Formatters.Clear();
                    configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

                    //configure json settings
                    var jsonSettings = configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
                    jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = false, AllowIntegerValues = true });
                    jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                });
                app.ConfigureAppBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseNancy(options =>
                    {
                        options.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(_config);
                        //options.PerformPassThrough
                    });
                });
                app.ConfigureStartOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Port = _config.LicenseServicePort;
                    //options.Urls = new List<string>(){};
                });
            });

            //add host reservation during service install, this is the only time, nancy will have admin rights, will be deleted when service is uninstalled as well.
            //nc => nancyConfig
            //sc.WithNancyEndpoint(host, nc =>
            //{
            //    nc.AddHost(port: _config.LicenseServicePort);
            //    nc.CreateUrlReservationsOnInstall();
            //    nc.DeleteReservationsOnUnInstall();
            //    nc.OpenFirewallPortsOnInstall(firewallRuleName: "mycustomservice");
            //    nc.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(_config);
            //});
        });

        host.SetDescription("Licensing service for my api.");
        host.SetDisplayName("myservice");
        host.SetServiceName("myservice);
        host.RunAsNetworkService();
        host.StartAutomatically();
    }
```

Comment: Any luck on answers? even I am looking for help in Nancy

Comment: In all honesty, we are going to move away from nancy alltogether. I wasn't fund of it, and support seems to be bad. I mean, nearly no help on multiple places, development is really slow, ...  Certain things that work out of the box in mvc with owin, where a hell to set up in nancy (DryIoc, swagger, property injection (I want to step away from this alltogether as well)). The only reason we choose Nancy was because other people took a wrong turn with MVC and Owin. 

For new projects we will be targeting asp .net core 2.1

if it is any help, I will post what we used back then as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted answer for codetoshare

```
private static void CreateHost(HostConfigurator host)
    {
        Log.Logger = SetupLogging();
        host.SetStartTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        //Plug serilog into host: log startup urls and start / stop
        host.UseSerilog(Log.Logger);

        //Allow to be run on linux as well
        host.UseLinuxIfAvailable();

        //sc => serviceconfigurator, ls => licenseService
        host.Service<WebService>(sc =>
        {
            //basic topshelf configuration
            sc.ConstructUsing(name => new WebService());
            sc.WhenStarted(ls => ls.Start());
            sc.WhenStopped(ls =>
            {
                ls.Stop();
                DisposeLogging();
            });
            //I am using an extension here because I had converted the application from Nancy.Host.Self to Nancy.Owin
            //if the extension will not get updated and this breaks the application, convert it to a normal app: see nearly every topshelf + owin example
            //owin configuration
            sc.OwinEndpoint(app =>
            {
                app.ConfigureHttp(configuration =>
                {
                    //use json.net serializer
                    configuration.Formatters.Clear();
                    configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

                    //configure json settings
                    var jsonSettings = configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
                    jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = false, AllowIntegerValues = true });
                    jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                });

                app.ConfigureAppBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    //setup windows authentication
                    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)builder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
                    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

                    //setup nancy
                    builder.UseNancy(options =>
                    {
                        options.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(_config);
                    });
                });
                //setup urls: always add localhost and 127.0.0.1 together with the host specified in the config file
                app.ConfigureStartOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Port = _config.LicenseServicePort;
                    var localhost = $"http://localhost:{_config.LicenseServicePort}";
                    var localhost2 = $"http://127.0.0.1:{_config.LicenseServicePort}";
                    //todo: this should support https as well
                    //todo: allow multiple hosts to be specified on config
                    options.Urls.Add(localhost);
                    options.Urls.Add(localhost2);
                    var configuredHost = $"{_config.LicenseServiceUrl}:{_config.LicenseServicePort}";
                    if (!configuredHost.Equals(localhost) && !configuredHost.Equals(localhost2))
                    {
                        options.Urls.Add(configuredHost);
                    }
                });
            });

            //old nancyhost config, keep this untill documented on confluence
            //add host reservation during service install, this is the only time, nancy will have admin rights, will be deleted when service is uninstalled as well.
            //nc => nancyConfig
            //sc.WithNancyEndpoint(host, nc =>
            //{
            //    nc.AddHost(port: _config.LicenseServicePort);
            //    nc.CreateUrlReservationsOnInstall();
            //    nc.DeleteReservationsOnUnInstall();
            //    nc.OpenFirewallPortsOnInstall(firewallRuleName: "SegreyLicensingService");
            //    nc.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(_config);
            //});
        });
```